# How to read data from an external hardware device using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, usb, data-transfer, hardware-interface

I have developed a simple software using VB.net, now i want to receive some data from an external device, i want to know if any way to learn "**How to read a hardware transmitted data using VB.net, where hardware is attached to a USB port?**" Any specific book or any way to get this thing learn.

Looking forward to hear from you all.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the data from a USB port in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296609/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-usb-port-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not duplicate the question:-

Still i was searching and found the answer from the following link, so again posting it here so that people should not search more for this. Thabnks

[How to get the data from a USB port in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296609/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-usb-port-in-vb-net)

Here is what I found. You use the **HID.dll** to interface the usb ports. And you know the best part? I found some examples.

Here's a link that contains basic examples and tutorial for usb interfacing. [The HID Page](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm)

[Sample Project File](http://www.lvr.com/files/generic_hid_vb_50.zip)