# approach to read data from USB in vb.net and make a driver for a device

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, usb

I have no experience in doing a driver or such a thing, the case is I am in a project where some data is sent from a device via usb, I want to interpret the data and use it in a vb.net program.

I am planning to program in assembly the function to store data received from device to a text file, then in vb.net program read this data and then do the rest.

Is there a better option to make an interface between vb.net and a device via usb?

I have found in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296609/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-usb-port-in-vb-net) the use of **HID.dll** to [interface the usb ports](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm). 
with a tutorial  [and sample code](http://www.lvr.com/files/generic_hid_vb_50.zip)

What would be a better option if I can control the data transmission rate of data?

All of this is in a Windows environment

[Sample Project File](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/), this is C# but you can add this as your `reference` or `dll` in your VB.NET project.