# Finding USB Devices from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, usb

My background is that I have been supporting a Vb5 application which controls my customers equipment in real time. He is now developing a new control board which will be connected to the PC via USB.

As I understand it connecting the device will generate a Com port. At the same time we will upgrade to VB.net, which is new to me.

I have Visual studio 2015 Community edition. I have written a routine using GetPortnames to ascertain how many com ports there are and what numbers (COM4, etc) they have.

How do I find what USB devices, if any, are attached to the com ports together with any identifying data of the device?

Answer (score 0):

Already answered, next time please google first.

The key word that I type in google was: **vb usb**

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296609/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-usb-port-in-vb-net)

Comment: Sorry, I searched for hours before I posted.  Your answer appears to tell me how to find removeable storeage.  I am looking for any device attached to a com port. I fail to see how my question has been answered.