# How to intercept/send usb signal between a pc and devices in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, usb, joystick

I would like to learn how a pc comunicate with a usb device and vice versa.
For example i have a Logitech Attack3 joystick connected to my pc, with its driver installed. I create my project with a trackBar or progressBar and would like it moves as i move the stick on the joystick. Could you please link something were i can study how to do this. I tried to search the web with no results. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data from a USB port in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296609/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-usb-port-in-vb-net)

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Is it general question about usb communication (duplicate) or "How to communicate with joysick"?

Comment: I would like to move the trackBar on my form, mouving the joystick stick (vertically for example). So what are the commands to intercept USB signals.